# Why should we conduct a yajna according to the Mimamsa Sutra?

Tags: vedas, purva-mimamsa, vedic-rituals

Mimamsa sutra is not about the existence of God but how Vedic rites are helful for social cohesion and humanity. 
Can anybody explain with verses what and how they (Jamini, or Kumarila Bhatt) show the benefits of a Vedic ritual are...?

Comment: It can be found in main vedas itself

Comment: I think you are mentioning the Brahmanas that accompany the Samhitas. No, if that were the case, Jamini and Kumarila Bhatt would not have written about Mimasika...

Comment: if mimamsa and other texts say about yajnas that dont mean vedas dont talk about it. There is glorification of many yagas like soma yaga in vedas. However i think someone may answer from mimamsa also..

Comment: Vedas talk about how yagnas serve the Brahman. It is theistic whether we like it or not.

Comment: On the other hand, Mimamsa is not concerned about any God and want to only show that yagnas have empirically test-able social benefits.